# Get Field Weights Programmatically

Tags: entities, 10

I have a custom module which ultimately creates a node of a given type. It gets the fields of that node type and creates my own form with them, HOWEVER, it does not preserve that node's order of fields.

I can do it manually, but would prefer to follow one of the display mode's configuration, like 'view' or 'form'

How can I access the field weights in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $build is your own form, keyed by field names, you can try something like this:

```
$display = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')
  ->getFormDisplay('node', 'given_type');

foreach ($display->getComponents() as $name => $options) {
  if (isset($build[$name])) {
    $build[$name]['#weight'] = $options['weight'];
  }
}
```

Comment: YES! that seems to do the trick.  Thank you.